# How to programmatically build a reliable URL to Facebook entries (posts, comments, etc)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I notices that if you grab the `post_id`, `parent_id`, or `comment_id` that the Facebook APIs return (both the Graph API and the old one) and build the URL like this:

```
https://facebook.com/{$comment_id}
```

which will look something like this:

```
https://facebook.com/1120222941346063_1783629701671357
```

Facebook will automatically determine what entry that is, and link you directly to it, scrolling down to the exact entry and highlighting it in orange, just if you had given it the exact URL for that entry (something like: `https://facebook.com/{$page_id}/posts/{$post_id}?comment_id={$comment_id}`).

My question is: is using those ID codes to build URLs as in the first example a reliable way to do it? Will it work for all entries or are there unexpected effects I might encounter?

In all my tests it always worked, but I didn't find anything in the official documentation or in other SO questions.

Comment: As long as you got the full, proper ID, it should work for most objects that have a UI representation. Some nodes (posts, photos, videos, comments, ...) also have a `permalink_url` field, although for comments at least that gives you a URL that is not much different from the one you created, Facebook will then redirect to the right location from there.

Comment: @CBroe Unfortunately the `permalink_url` field does not come with all entities. For example, all photo comments I tests do come with a `permalink_url`, but it's under the `post` field, and it's a URL to the actual post, not the comment itself. Though yeah, you can build from that, but it's still more complicated than just appending the `comment_id` to `facebok.com/.